# Save "report a problem" as a plain text file

Tags: error-handling

I am getting a "report a problem" message right after boot. I would like to find the cause of the problem. To do so, I would like to save the error messages.

I realize I can *probably* extract it from dmesg, but is there a way to just save the output? Say send the report to my email, or as a plain text locally? Screenshoots do the job, but this is an ugly solution.

Answer (score 6):

You find the error report files created by `apport` in the directory

```
/var/crash/
```

The files are named with the following scheme:

```
_underscore_separated_path_to_executable.UserID.crash
```

So for example when `qtox` recently crashed running as user with UID 1000, it created the following file:

```
/var/crash/_usr_bin_qtox.1000.crash
```

It's a simple but very long (up to several MB) ASCII text file which you can open in any editor. It looks like this, for example (only the first few lines, of course):

```
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CrashCounter: 1
CurrentDesktop: Unity
Date: Tue Nov 17 12:30:26 2015
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 15.10
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/qtox
ExecutableTimestamp: 1447542999
ProcCmdline: qtox
ProcCwd: /home/alphawolf
ProcEnviron:
[...]
```